# Control meteor package loading

Tags: meteor, controls, loading, package, accounts

How can I control how/when meteor packages are loading?

I'm hosting a game on my site using accounts-ui and accounts-facebook but the game isn't on the main site. However, the accounts-ui stuff are still clogging up my main page and making it take a long time to load.

Also, anyone know why accounts-ui is loading so much? (It's adding .8 MB to my meteor site).

Comment: Meteor loads everything at the beginning of the app - so you can't control **when** something is loaded, only **if** it is loaded.

Comment: In that case, I would consider writing my own login UI :)